# Different bytes read from which I wrote

Tags: java, byte, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to write a byte array to file and then to read it again. The problem is that the byte array that I Read is different from that I wrote.
The output of the code below is:

> [B@21a06946 (Original byte array written)
>
> [B@2fc14f68 (byte array read )

```
        byte[] encryptedKey = rsaCipher.encrypt(AESKey, publicKeyPathName, transformation, encoding);
        System.out.println(encryptedKey);
        List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        list.add(encryptedKey);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("encryptedKey"));
        out.writeObject(list);
        out.close();


        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("encryptedKey"));
        List<byte[]> byteList = (List<byte[]>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        byte[] encryptedKey2 = byteList.get(0);

        System.out.println(encryptedKey2);
```

Comment: The instance is different, but have you checked the content?

Comment: This is not how you check for array equality, use Arrays.equals(byte[]1,byte[]2) instead

Comment: When you see a string like `[B@...` you should notice that it's a variable reference and not its content. `[` stands for array, `B` for `byte` and `@...` for "at ...".

Answer (score 2):

Arrays do not have a proper String representation. To see the content, use the below instead

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(encryptedKey));
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(encryptedKey2));
```

Comment: Actually I could think about by myself, thank you very much!

Comment: @user3376554 If my answer helped you, can you please accept it? :)